# Difference between Atomic Operation and Thread Safety?

Tags: c#, programming-languages, multithreading

From the discussion I've seen it seems that *atomic operation* and *thread safety* are the same thing, but a lot of people say that they're different. Can anyone tell me the difference if there is one?

Comment: Atomic operations will help ensuring thread safety, but how could they possibly be _the same thing_? A "thread" is not the same as a "operation".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Atomic operations are a way to achive thread safety either by using some kind of locks like [Mutexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) or [Semaphores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) which use atomic operations internally or by implementing [lock free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm) synchronization using atomics and memory fences.

So atomic operations on primitive data types are a tool to achive thread safety but do not ensure thread safety automatically because you normally have multiple operations that rely on each other. You have to ensure that these operations are done without interruption eg using Mutexes.

Yes, writing one of these atomic data types in c# is thread safe, but that does not make the function you use them in thread safe. It only ensures that the single write is correctly executed even if a second thread accesses it "at the same time". Never the less, the next read from the current thread is not ensured to get the value previously written as a different thread might have written to it, only that the value read is valid.

Comment: Is int, bool, float are thread safe or atomic?

Comment: @user960567 - data types are just that: data types. It is up to the compiler to decide how to access them. Think of an int64 on a 8086 CPU.

Comment: None of those is ensured to be atomic on all platforms. You can use platform/compiler dependent methods like [InterlockedIncrement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms683614(v=vs.85).aspx) or the new [std::atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) of c++11. Even setting an integer can cause garbage when it is not aligned to the cache lines of your processor as two operations can result in one part getting written from one write and the other part from the other write, at least on PPC.

Comment: @mouviciel, see this what this thread say http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047280/is-int-thread-safe

Comment: @user960567 please note that that thread only relates to C# which ensures some operations to be atomic by using atomic operations and correct memory alignment internally.

Comment: In C# specifically, that the question is tagged with, reads and writes _must_ be atomic on the basic data-types. See [Ecma 334](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf)

Comment: And yes, writing one of these atomic data types in c# is thread safe, but that does not make the function you use them in thread safe. It only ensures that the single write is correctly executed even if a second thread accesses it "at the same time". Never the less, the next read from the current thread is not ensured to get the value previously written as a different thread might have written to it, only that the value read is valid.

Comment: @Archy, Please explain a little. I will very thankfull. I am confused here. If int is atomic then why we need to use interlock construct.

Comment: @user960567 the InterlockedIncrement allows incrementing an integer in memory, doing this without a special construct would not work. In C# setting eg x=x+1 is not atomic, only the read and write are which would lead to an increment not getting executed when two threads do it at the same time. Another interesting construct is compare and swap (CAS) which allows you to sync multiple threads because they can detect when another thread as changed the value since it was last read by the current thread and react to it.

Comment: @Arch, you are saying that reading int and writhing int is atomic. But x = x+1 is also writing? and what about x = 5, is this atomic?

Comment: x=5 is atomic in c#. But immediately after this operation it could be overwritten. 
x=x+1 is executed by 
1. loading x into register
2. increment x in register
3. store x into memory.
If a second thread does the same thing at the same time, both will load the same value, increment it and store it resulting in x only getting incremented once instead of twice. InterlockedIncrement either uses a special processor instruction to execute a atomic increment or ensures this by using a locking mechanism, eg CAS, to ensure that while the new value is not written no other thread may read the old value.

Answer (score 4):

An atomic operation is an operation that cannot be interrupted.

A safe thread is a thread that can safely be interrupted.

Thread safety is obtained with atomic operations, in particular in the logic that prevents critical resources from being accessed multiple times.

The basic atomic operation is [Test-and-set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set), which is used for implementing semaphores, which in turn are used to implement thread safety.

Comment: Cannot a multi-step operation be interrupted and be called atomic still if it is guaranteed to roll back it's changes?

Comment: No. Atomic is to be understood in its etymological meaning: ἄτομος, atomos,  indivisible.

Comment: Is int, bool, float are thread safe or atomic?

Comment: But isn't there's a difference between _being_ indivisble, and _appearing_ indivisible to a _observer_? By your definition, not atomic operation could contain more than a single step. I believe the "appears" word in [wikipedia's definition of Atomic operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_operation) is important. (I'm in the chat if anyone wants to bring it up there) :)

Comment: There is one big difference: a safe thread can be interrupted, and there is no garantee of how much time. This is critical in realtime computing. An atomic operation (with interrupt locks if it is multi-step) is garanteed to terminate after a predictable amount of time.

Answer (score 3):

Atomicity and thread-safety are two different things. Atomicity refers to an operation's "all-or-nothing" quality; if an operation cannot be performed 100% successfully, then the system should remain in the overall state it had been in before any part of the operation began. The classic example is a database transaction; When saving an invoice, including its header and multiple line items, every single part of every single database row must be put in place successfully; if not, data is lost or corrupted. If a line item cannot be inserted, then not only should no other rows remaining be inserted, but none of the rows already processed should remain.

Thread-safety refers to a combination of things, including atomicity, that allows an operation to be "reentrant"; multiple workers can be performing the same operation, starting at the same or different times, without effect on any other. There are many models for thread-safe operation; most of them boil down conceptually to either running multiple parallel tasks in complete isolation (two workers can perform the same task on two different objects or collections of objects without ever knowing the other worker even exists), or setting up a "pipeline" within which multiple workers each perform one task out of an entire operation (either each worker progresses from the first task to the next and so on, or else focuses on one task and hands off its intermediate "work product" to the next worker).

Answer (score 1):

Thread-safety is more a framework or a "concept", atomic operation is a subset, a means (one of many) of achieving status as being classed 'thread-safe'.

Thread safety refers to a process that can be accessed by separate threads, where the access of one (and manipulation of data), wont corrupt the integrity of the operation of the other.

Much of the skill of the programmer is knowing how to achieve this, depending on the situation and key objective, you may need to implement, for example: locks, semaphores, latches, atomic objects, synchronization rules etc...